# Woocommerce get category image full size

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, images, terms

i'm trying to get the full size image of my category products.

```
    $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ));

    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );?>

        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /></a>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query();
```

The above code works, but it returns an image of 150px x 150 even when adjustments in Woocommerce are like this:

[image: My Woocommerce product settings]

I´d like to get a larger size or full size.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Jolley (Woocommerce plugin author) for the solution using: `wp_get_attachment_image_src`

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ));

    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog' );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );?>

        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /></a>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Great answer. Just a heads up anyone coming across this. `get_woocommerce_term_meta` is deprecated since version 3.6. Use `get_term_meta` instead. Tested and working in 5.4.1.